# SignalR client side for Xamarin Form

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, signalr, signalr.client

i have ASP MVC project with SignalR ready.it uses signalr to send messages from one user to another.
currently i'm trying to make an android app to use signalr functions.
how can i implement signalr client side into Xamarin form and how can i tell signalr functions to call those client side functions in xamarin?
is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft offers the [SignalR Core .NET Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-2.2) NuGet package. This package is made to communicate with SignalR hubs in every .NET project.

However, there are special [requirements](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/305) to use it with Xamarin:

> Xamarin has special requirements for Visual Studio version. For more information, see [SignalR Client 2.1.1 in Xamarin](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/305).

Answer (score 0):

yup it is possibile. you can check the code here:

https://github.com/edgarleonardo/ChatAppXamarinFormWithWebSocket

or here:

https://github.com/IncredibleWeb/Xamarin-Forms-Chat-Client